# Response::json() doesn't return anything with Nginx + laravel 4

Tags: php, json, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I have an API in Laravel 4 which returns response in JSON format.

```
return Response::json(array('users' => $users ));
```

But I am getting a blank response while calling this api endpoint from Angular or Postman. I can see the 'Content-Type' is set to 'text/html'. It is returning json response as 'text/html'.

After searching on web, most people suggested to add json in mime.types file, I have checked /etc/nginx/mime.types and it already contains

```
application/json        json;
```

The same thing is returning proper response when running with Apache.

Also when I am running this api call from entering the url in browser, it is returning proper response.

Is there anyone else encounter this kind of problem ?

Comment: What status code do you get returned?

Comment: @noodles_ftw I am getting 200

Comment: Did you restart nginx after setting the mime.types?

Comment: @Jeemusu Actually it was already set, but still I did a restart the service

Comment: Did you check `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`, try adding a header in there for a .json extension ?

`location ~ \.json {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/json;
}`

Could also be that it's being served by fastcgi due to the location.

Comment: @Jeemusu Tried adding that line in configuration file but still no success.

Comment: I have the same error.

Comment: Any solution so far?

Comment: Did you find Any solution?